# pandas mix type value list: move string at the end of the list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I try to organize by a column value in ascending order. In this column, there are some values that are strings, I want to move them at the bottom of the dataframe but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have this:

```
   index Transporteur     Prix 
0      0      t1      'unavailable'
1      0      t2           66          
2      0      t3          145       
3      0      t4         401.3
```

when i do

```
 final_df = final_df.sort_values('Prix', ascending=True).reset_index()
 final_df = final_df.replace(0.00,'unavailable')
```

the "unavailable" value gets printed out at the top but I need it at the bottom.

Sorry if this sounds like a noob question but honestly I cannot find a way to fix it. Thank you for any help!

Comment: If this is numeric feature and here `'unavailable'` indicate missing value then better to replace `'unavailable'` with `NaN` and convert into numeric type - `df["Prix"] = pd.to_numeric(df.Prix,'coerce')`. And then perform other operations on the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`:

```
final_df = final_df.loc[pd.to_numeric(final_df['Prix'], errors='coerce').sort_values().index]
```

**Output:**

```
   index Transporteur           Prix
1      0           t2             66
2      0           t3            145
3      0           t4          401.3
0      0           t1  'unavailable'
```